# Paramiko not working properly after cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cx-freeze

so I've writing this code where I connect to a computer over SSH using Paramiko, the script works normally, but when I convert it to ".exe" using cx_Freeze the program stops working at "self.ssh.load_system_host_keys", so i remove that function from the script and it kept working as usual (maybe not always needed?), but then again, when I converted the script to .exe, it was the "self.ssh.connect" function of Paramiko which now seems to be stopping the program, and by that i mean, no exception raises, the code just stops running right there and nothing happens, any thoughts?.

Are there any compatibility issues with Paramiko and cx_Freeze?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

**session.py** (Class in which I implemented the paramiko functionality)

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

class Session:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.is_connected = False
        self.ssh = SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())


    def assert_connection(self):
        # force connection
        time_start = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                self.ssh.connect(self.host, username=self.user, password=self.password)
                self.is_connected = True
                return True
            except:
                print(time.time() - time_start)
                if (time.time() - time_start) > 3:
                    self.ssh.close()
                    return False
```

The "Main" Script

```
 import session
 import threading     

 def create_session(self):
      self.session = session.Session(self, self.active_session.host,
      self.active_session.user, self.active_session.password)
      t = threading.Thread(target=self.connect_via_ssh)
      t.start()

def connect_via_ssh(self):
    if self.session.assert_connection():
         #Do something
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

I wasn't able to figure out what was going wrong, however i tryed using pyinstaller, and it did work! i bet there's some wierd bug with cx_freeze and paramiko.

Comment: I use paramiko in a pyinstaller frozen exe no problem ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley it did work, thank you!