# Python DLL ImportError cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to convert script below into an exe, but I think that even including the package cryptography, when the tool is executed in another machine, DLL importerror pronpts out, any idea of how I can solve it?, thanks!

error

```
trying import.... 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 23, in run
  File "pod pdf merge tool.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 195, in <module>
  File "XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 142, in init_static_locks
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

script.py

```
print ("trying import.... 1")
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import Backend as OpenSSLBackend
print ("import ok")
print ("trying import... 2")
import pysftp
from pysftp import CnOpts
print ("import ok")
import re
import _ssl
import os, msvcrt
print ("trying import... 3")
import cryptography
print ("import ok")
import time
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
```

setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

packages = ['pysftp','time','bcrypt','pycparser','six','re','msvcrt','os','PyPDF2','paramiko','cryptography','cffi']
includes = ['_cffi_backend']


# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages":packages,'includes': includes}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None

setup(  name = "POD PDF Merger tool",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "V1",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("pod pdf merge tool.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: Edit: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660621/paramiko-not-working-properly-after-cx-freeze. "I wasn't able to figure out what was going wrong, however i tryed using pyinstaller, and it did work! i bet there's some wierd bug with cx_freeze and paramiko."

Answer (score 0):

This may appear if `openssl` isn't installed on your machine or in anaconda.

Comment: Thanks! But, seems more an issue with cx_freeze and paramiko. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660621/paramiko-not-working-properly-after-cx-freeze